# Not able to debug an XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Here is my XSD. I am not able to understand why I keep getting this error:

> CDIER0202E: Internal Fatal DOM error encountered while loading XML
>   schema=:urn|library|Test123247_1|resource|SmallCase.xsd:urn|library|Test123247_1|resource|SmallCase.xsd:urn|library|Test123247_1|resource|SmallCase.xsd:3:35:322:The
>   prefix "xsd" for element "xsd:element" is not bound..

Here is the new XSD after edits:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:scotiaXML="http://xml.scotia.com"  targetNamespace="http://xml.scotia.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
<!-- Begin Level 1 =============================================-->
<xsd:element name="OTC_Matching" type="temp"/>
<xsd:complexType name="temp" mixed="false">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element ref="PostTrade"/>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<!-- End Level 1 =============================================-->
<xsd:element name="PostTrade" type="PostTradeTransaction"/>
<xsd:complexType name="PostTradeTransaction" abstract="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="elem1" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: You declared the namespace xs, but are using the prefix xsd. Change xsd to xs at a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is you haven't assigned the namespace xsd to anything. Why are you using xs and xsd ? I think you want to replace xsd with xs everywhere.

A second problem is you haven't provided a close  tag.

A third problem is that you have not indicated that PostTrade is in a sequence with OTC_Matching.

Can you provide a sample xml you want to validate with this schema?

This gets further and gives me the error:

```
D:\downloads>\bin\xmllint.exe --schema y.xsd x1.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OTC_Matching xmlns="http://xml.scotia.com">
<PostTrade>
<elem1/>
</PostTrade>
</OTC_Matching>
x1.xml:2: element PostTrade: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://xml.scoti
a.com}PostTrade': The type definition is abstract.
x1.xml fails to validate
```

With this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:scotiaXML="http://xml.scotia.com" targetNamespace="http://xml.scotia.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
  <!-- Begin Level 1 =============================================-->
  <xs:element name="OTC_Matching">
    <xs:complexType mixed="false">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="PostTrade" type="scotiaXML:PostTradeTransaction"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <!-- End Level 1 =============================================-->
  <xs:complexType name="PostTradeTransaction" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="elem1" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: It was detected that 'temp' has no namespace, but components with no target namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'urn|library|Test123247_1|resource|SmallCase.xsd'. If 'temp' is intended to have a namespace, perhaps a prefix needs to be provided. If it is intended that 'temp' has no namespace, then an 'import' without a "namespace" attribute should be added to 'urn|library|Test123247_1|resource|SmallCase.xsd'.

Comment: Sorry, your link to the complete xsd is not visible

Comment: thanks after you inputs I made the following changes:<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="foo" version="1.0" >
 <xsd:element name="OTC_Matching">
 <xsd:complexType mixed="false">
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:choice>
 <xsd:element ref="PostTrade" xmlns="foo"/>
 </xsd:choice>
 </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
 <xsd:element name="PostTrade" type="PostTradeTransaction" xmlns="foo"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="PostTradeTransaction" abstract="true" xmlns="foo">
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:choice>
 <xsd:element ref="PostTrade" xmlns="foo"/>.

Answer (score 0):

The correct xsd is:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="foo" version="1.0" >
<!-- Begin Level 1 =============================================-->
<xsd:element name="OTC_Matching">
    <xsd:complexType mixed="false">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element ref="PostTrade" xmlns="foo"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<!-- End Level 1 =============================================-->
<xsd:element name="PostTrade" type="PostTradeTransaction" xmlns="foo"/>
<xsd:complexType name="PostTradeTransaction" abstract="true" xmlns="foo">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element ref="PostTrade" xmlns="foo"/>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: I missed: </xsd:schema> at the end.